# Error code AADB2C90157 from Azure AD B2C while login

Tags: azure, azure-activedirectory

We are using Azure AD B2C as identity provider. Some time when users tries to login, we are getting error as

```
AADB2C90157 : User has exceeded the maximum number for retries for a self-asserted step. 

Correlation ID : <CorrelationID> 
Timestamp : <Timestamp>.
```

I searched online to get information on error code but none could be found. Can you guys let me what this error code means.

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1):

This could happen when you have reached maximum retries with errors when using an email address to reset a password which has never been registered by the user.

You can reproduce it with a password reset policy and put an non-exist email address. After receiving the verification code, hit continue button for more than 3 times.